# add-content produces stream not readable

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that dumps a gazillion lines to a csv file while processing a very large XML.

During the while read of the xml reader I write each line to a csv file like so:

```
  $newline | add-content -path $csv_file
```

This works for 99% but occasionally I see in the log "add-content: stream was not readable" for 1 or 2 items out of gazillions, I presume because it is busy writing the past line to it.

Any resolution?

Comment: How are you reading the XML file?

Comment: like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820590/how-can-i-use-xmlreader-in-powershell-to-stream-big-huge-xml-files

Comment: is `$newline` just a string? Does the script fail always for the same item or is it random?

Comment: You can nail this down easily with a try/catch...

Comment: like i said above only intermediate, i guess when the output stream is busy

Comment: so... how to nail it down with a try catch? when i would use a try catch it display me the exception... which is exactly what i now have. so that is no resolution i think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a PowerShell approach if you don't want to call the windows API.  Put in a try catch block within a do loop to retry until successful.

```
    $isWritten = $false

    do {
        try {
            Add-Content -Path $csv_file -Value $newline -ErrorAction Stop
            $isWritten = $true
        }
        catch {
        }
    } until ( $isWritten )
}
```

Comment: This is 5 years later and im totally outside of that project long ago, but it looks like something i will add to all entries where add-content is used. Maybe even add max 5 retries. Maybe by default wrap Add-Content.

Answer (score 12):

Its an old post, but I run into a similar problem (using `Set-Content` instead of `Add-Content`). 
In my case, the [WriteAllText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) Method solved that issue.

This should solve it for you:

```
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($csv_file,$newline)
```